# How to set the nomerge option in .NET WebBrowser control?

Tags: webbrowser-control, session-state, chromium-embedded, open-webkit-sharp

I launch IE with the "nomerge" option while testing our web applications, when I need to login as two different users at the same time. I would like to know if the same option is available with the .NET web browser control? (or for that matter with other web browser controls such as geckofx or webkitsharp) I want to launch two web browser controls inside the same winforms test application and be able to login as two different users.

Comment: You cannot do this for `WebBrowser` control (search for "WebBrowser" and "session", it's a repeating question here). Your best bet with `WebBrowser` would be to not use cookies for session control and do it via URL, if possible. This is a limitation of the underlying URLMON/WinInet layers. I can't answer the part of your question about Gecko or Webkit-based controls, though.